# How to prevent the Random Walk Algorithm from getting 'stuck'?

Tags: c, algorithm

I am making a rogue-like game and I am using a random walk within a grid to form a 'cave' system. However, the random walk I have came up with gets stuck-- in particular when the walker is near the edge of the grid and is surrounded with 'holes.'

This isn't the exact code I am using in my project, I cannot access my code from work. However, I re-wrote a sample of the same algorithm I am using at home.

Essentially, I took a 20x20 grid of integers and filled it with 1's. As I walk I punch a 0 on each step I take.

```
void walk(int grid[][20]){
  int x = rand() % 10 + 9;
  int y = rand() % 10 + 9;

  int walk_count;

  for(walk_count = rand() % 1000 + 500; walk_count >= 0; walk_count--){
    switch(rand() % 4){
      case 0: if(grid[x][y - 1] == 1 && y - 1 >= 1){ y--; grid[x][y] = 0;} break;
      case 1: if(grid[x][y + 1] == 1 && y + 1 < 20){ y++; grid[x][y] = 0;} break;
      case 2: if(grid[x - 1][y] == 1 && x - 1 >= 1){ x--; grid[x][y] = 0;} break;
      case 3: if(grid[x + 1][y] == 1 && x + 1 < 20){ x++; grid[x][y] = 0;} break;
      default: break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: try a depth first search instead and use more complex rules than if the adjacent cell has not been visited yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, explain the asymmetry in your code. In case 1, you have `&& y + 1 < 20`. In case 3, you have `&& x + 1 >= 1`, which I would expect to be `&& x + 1 < 20`.

I'm going to chalk that up as a transcription error / typo and not the source of your problem. As I understand it, your problem is that you have a random walker who paints the floor and is painting itself into a corner. This behavior is expected, isn't it?

The problem is that you are simply doing a random walk and expecting a behavior that is more intelligent than random. If you want to avoid painting yourself into a corner, put that into your algorithm. Assuming these random walkers want to be able to reach the player, just check that each direction, if filled, would still have a path to the player. Then randomly choose from the directions where that holds true.

Comment: Thanks for the transcription error. I see what you're saying-- I have not included a player yet but I can see how randomly choosing a start and exit point, and having the walkers attempt to make it to the exit would help make the cave better designed.

Comment: Reachability of the exit is good. However, I suggest a design check: make sure your player has a chance of reaching the exit. If I start at one end of a 20x20 room and need to make it to the other side, then there comes a point where too many random walkers punching holes in the ground are almost guaranteed to cut me off, even if I play with an optimal strategy.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for you:

**first use graphs:** each cell is vertex and if two cells are adjacent and both 1 then there is an edge in the graph between their vertexes.

Now when walking to a new cell and putting 0 in it you breaking all the edges the were connected to it's vertex.

What we have here it that now you can look at the connected components in the graph and tell if there is a path between two cells(if they're in the same connected component then there is a path), since you probably have some kind of exit from the cave so it's gonna be the special cell, and now you can construct a rule weather the cell is "good" only if it's in the same connected component as the special cell.

**At last:** your condition of walking will be only if the adjacent cell is "good"(from before) with this condition you will never end in a dead end :) since you always will have a path to your exit(can be more then one :) no prob)

hope you like this solution, check **more about graphs here**:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29